# Prestashop create Grid

Tags: php, grid, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I try to create a custom Grid in Prestashop 1.7 without using the query builder. Is that possible? For example from array,collection or json data.

This is the tutorial from Prestashop doc. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/grid/

```
# Register ProductQueryBuilder
prestashop.core.grid.query.product_query_builder:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Query\ProductQueryBuilder'
    parent: 'prestashop.core.grid.abstract_query_builder'
    arguments:
        - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().language.id"
        - "@=service('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context').getContext().shop.id"
    public: true
    
# Configure our Grid Data factory to use the query builder that we registered above
prestashop.core.grid.data.factory.product_data_factory:
    class: 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Data\Factory\DoctrineGridDataFactory'
    arguments:
        - '@prestashop.core.grid.query.product_query_builder' # service id of our query builder
        - '@prestashop.core.hook.dispatcher' # every doctrine query builder needs the hook dispatcher
        - '@prestashop.core.grid.query.doctrine_query_parser' # parser to get the raw SQL query
        - 'products' # this should match your grid id, in our case it's "products"
```

Any Ideas to remplace the **ProductQueryBuilder** with array,collection or json data ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a DataTable for this cases.

You can use DataTable to from a table generated in a template file. This is the fastest way to make it work, but it could consume some memory if you have a lot of data.

The official DataTable documentation is a goog start: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

You could also go for a DataTable based in AJAX to do it dynamically, but you would have to take care about the security and session expiration by your self.

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/

These videos might give you some ideas to set the DataTable and the AJAX backend. Pay attention to the security details in the second video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=186DFIV_IDs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoTqmzi6-1g